# Changing Default python path on Mac OS

Tags: python, django, macos

I've been doing some research on this matter but could not find a proper solution. python by default is preinstalled on Mac OS. I'm currently trying to run python 3.6 and above, but when I am using Django and creating a new virtual environment, it is referencing python 2.7. I have downloaded the newest version of python, but that does not seem to overwrite python 2.7.

I believe the issue has to do with the default path of python on Macs. How would I go and change that path so that when I create a virtual environment and when I use the Django framework, it will reference python 3.6 instead of python 2.7 ?

Comment: 1. Make sure you install Python with a prefix of `/usr/local`. 2. Put `/usr/local/bin` at the front of your `PATH` (by adding it to `/etc/paths`). Someone may suggest replacing `/usr/bin/python`, but you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Have you tried :  $ virtualenv -p python3 <desired-path>

Comment: Both the solutions above worked! The first solution changes the default python version to the desired python version. The second solution only changes the virtual environment to python3 and above. But I guess from here on it is more preference, thank you!